# cloudControl - timeouts and fastcgi errors

Tags: php, fastcgi, cloudcontrol

During the past days, we almost always encountered timeouts on our PHP-application while the cloudControl error logfile displayed

```
Error [error] [client ...] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/app/php/box/php-fpm"
Error [error] [client ...] FastCGI: comm with server "/app/php/box/php-fpm" aborted: idle timeout (120 sec)
```

Will there be an issue with the standard memory limit settings and if so, what would be the best way to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a WordPress installation and most of the time these errors occur doing larger DB driven tasks. So we probably have to increase the containers RAM, which is currently at lowest (128MB).

Comment: You can try to increase the RAM, but it depends on where the time is spent. If it is on the database side, increasing the RAM for the application will not help. I suggest to add the NewRelic addon, which shows you pretty good, which are the most time consuming parts of your application.

Answer (score 2):

the error which you are observing in the log often comes from a too long running php process. The runtime is restricted to 120 seconds. In most of the cases, if your application 'suddenly' starts to print out these messages, it hast something to do with external services (database, web services, ...), which are answering slower than expected. If this is the case, it is a good practice to configure timeouts (socket) and handle the error case, to prevent your application being affected by other services.

I hope it helps.